# mysql SELECT with SUBSTRING, LOWER and REPLACE commands

Tags: mysql, select

Im trying to do a select on the company name(cpnm) field of our company table but only giving me the first 6 characters, replacing all spaces plus making it lowercase.

```
SELECT *,
SUBSTRING(LOWER(cpnm), -LENGTH(cpnm), 6) as test
FROM company
LIMIT 100
```

The above works fine but as soon as I try to add the replace spaces (shown below), it doesnt give back results.

```
SELECT *,
SUBSTRING(LOWER(REPLACE(cpnm, ' ', '')), -LENGTH(cpnm), 6) as test
FROM company
LIMIT 100
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to filter the output in PHP in stead of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by replacing the spaces you change the length of the string, therefore `substr()` doesn't work like you expect it.

Try `SELECT *,
SUBSTRING(LOWER(REPLACE(cpnm, ' ', '')), -LENGTH(REPLACE(cpnm, ' ', '')), 6) as test` instead!

Comment: thanks florian h,  ur a genius ^^ 
I might have got there myself after much messing about but Id spent about 20 minutes trying all sorts of ways round it.  many thanks.

Comment: One will overlook the most obvious solutions after thinking too much about it – you're welcome :)